# Тестирование транзакций в Java, работа через Spring AOP

Tags: java, тестирование, spring-aop

Cуть моего вопроса в том, что у меня back-end приложения, там есть два слоя, DAO слой и Service слой, некоторые классы сервисного слоя там представлены как классы с методами,которые должны выполняться в рамках транзакции. При тестировании, с помощью мокито сервисного слоя, я не понимаю будут ли мои тестируемые методы выполняться в рамках транзакции или нет? Конфигурирую я транзакции с помощью Spring Aop в XML файле с помощью советов и и менеджера транзакций

Comment: Формируя вопрос, ориентируйтесь на то, что это может помочь кому-то в дальнейшем. В таком формате, как задали вы, вопрос не содержит полезной информации и его закроют.

Comment: Какие могут быть транзакции, если вы подменяете саму базу данных?

Comment: @Etki Но все же, метод же должен отработать, я же ведь могу задать ему поведение, поведение любому методу из могего сервиса. Что, равзе как транзакция он не будет отрабатывать?

Comment: Нет, потому что транзакций физически нет.

Comment: @Etki Хорошо, а вооще я могу как-нибудь образом это все протестировать?

Comment: Да не нужно вообще в принципе тестировать базу данных